# error sending message with android SmsManager

Tags: android, sms

i am working on android application for sending SMS. I have put permission on `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I have used following code to send sms.

```
SmsManager sm =SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Using this code i can send message only once. If i try to send sms next time the message cannot be sent even with my application and by texting.

Comment: Do you get any error ? Post more code may be the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class SMS extends Activity {
     ...

     private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {        
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
         SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. At first, i follow the tutorial by mkyong here :(http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/)

The first SMS was sent successfully, but not the subsequent ones.

After that, i looked at this other tutorial, which sends an pendingIntent after the 'sendTestMessage()'. It works and can send multiple SMS. Working tutorial below :
(http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)